# Generic Sequences

Tags: generics, sequence, nim-lang

I have the following snippet. The second variable declaration does not compile though:

```
type 
  Coin = ref object
  Pen  = ref object

let 
  yes : seq[ref object] = @[Coin(), Coin(), Coin()]  #Compiles
  no  : seq[ref object] = @[Coin(), Pen(), Coin()]   #Does not compile
```

Is it possible in nim to have generic seqs, like java's list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nim sequences *are* generic, but you are not putting the same kind of objects in them. In Java all non-primitive types (including arrays) [inherit either directly or indirectly from the Object superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and therefore by having a `List<Object>` type you can put anything in it. But in Nim not everything has to have the same root, and in your case, while the objects look the same, they are treated as different types. So you need to create a class hierarchy like java:

```
type
  BaseRef = ref object of TObject
  CoinRef = ref object of BaseRef
  PenRef = ref object of BaseRef

let
  test1: seq[BaseRef] = @[(BaseRef)CoinRef(), CoinRef(), CoinRef()]
  test2: seq[BaseRef] = @[(BaseRef)CoinRef(), PenRef(), CoinRef()]
```

Note that the `@[]` list constructor still needs prodding in the correct direction converting the first element to the base type or you will get an inequality (a `seq[BaseRef]` is **not** the same as a `seq[CoinRef]`, which would result from type inference).

If you need for some reason to keep separate roots, being refs it should be ok to cast them directly, for which you can create helper procs:

```
type 
  AnyRef = ref object
  Coin = ref object
  Pen  = ref object

proc `^`(x: Coin): AnyRef = cast[AnyRef](x)
proc `^`(x: Pen): AnyRef = cast[AnyRef](x)

let 
  yes : seq[AnyRef] = @[^Coin(), ^Coin(), ^Coin()]
  no  : seq[AnyRef] = @[^Coin(), ^Pen(), ^Coin()]
```

Or maybe create [converter procs](http://nim-lang.org/manual.html#converters) which don't require explicit conversion for all the elements, only the first, like with the inheritance version:

```
type 
  AnyRef = ref object
  Coin = ref object
  Pen  = ref object

converter toAnyRef(x: Coin): AnyRef = cast[AnyRef](x)
converter toAnyRef(x: Pen): AnyRef = cast[AnyRef](x)

let 
  yes : seq[AnyRef] = @[Coin().toAnyRef, Coin(), Coin()]
  no  : seq[AnyRef] = @[Coin().toAnyRef, Pen(), Coin()]
```

Comment: Great answer, as always. Thank you Grzegorz.